# CSS not working on django password form field

Tags: css, django, django-forms

I downloaded a css template from the web. I was able to link everything to my Django code execpt for the password fields and button styling.  What step am I missing missing? I have read the Django documentatin and I am using the attr metthod to add css attributes to my django form fields.
In my python code their seems to be a missing form attribute for password fields when implementing css.

#My Forms.py code

```
    class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    
    class Meta:
        model = User

        fields = [ 'username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']

        #applying form css rules where the item is a call to the css name or form attribute
        widgets={
            'username': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'un', 'type':'text', 'align':'center', 'placeholder':'UserName'}),
            'email':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'un', 'type':'text', 'align':'center', 'placeholder':'Email'}),
            'password1':forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'pass', 'type':'text', 'align':'center', 'placeholder':'password'}),
            'password2': forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'pass', 'type':'password', 'align':'center', 'placeholder':'password'}),
        }




#My View function

    def signup(request):
    form = CreateUserForm() 

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('login') 


    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, "testingapp/signup.html", context)

#My css code
        body {
        background-color: #F3EBF6;
        font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    }
    
    .main {
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
        margin: 7em auto;
        border-radius: 1.5em;
        box-shadow: 0px 11px 35px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
    }
    
    .sign {
        padding-top: 40px;
        color: #8C55AA;
        font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 23px;
    }
    
    .un {
    width: 76%;
    color: rgb(38, 50, 56);
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 14px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    background: rgba(136, 126, 126, 0.04);
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 20px;
    outline: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    margin-left: 46px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 27px;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    }
    
    form.form1 {
        padding-top: 40px;
    }
    
    .pass {
            width: 76%;
    color: rgb(38, 50, 56);
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 14px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    background: rgba(136, 126, 126, 0.04);
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 20px;
    outline: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    margin-left: 46px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 27px;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    }
    
   
    .un:focus, .pass:focus {
        border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18) !important;
        
    }
    
    .submit {
      cursor: pointer;
        border-radius: 5em;
        color: #fff;
        background: linear-gradient(to right, #9C27B0, #E040FB);
        border: 0;
        padding-left: 40px;
        padding-right: 40px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
        margin-left: 35%;
        font-size: 13px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 20px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
    }
    
    .forgot {
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(117, 117, 117, 0.12);
        color: #E1BEE7;
        padding-top: 15px;
    }
    
    
    input {
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(117, 117, 117, 0.12);
        color: #E1BEE7;
        text-decoration: none
    }
    
    @media (max-width: 600px) {
        .main {
            border-radius: 0px;
        }
    
    }
```

#My HTML

```
    {% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Signup</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'testingapp/style.css' %}"></style>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="">
{% csrf_token %}


<body>
    <div class="main">
        
      <p class="sign" align="center">SIGN UP</p>
      <form class="form1" action="" method="post">
        {{ form.username }}

        {{ form.email }}
        
        {{ form.password1 }}

        {{ form.password2 }}
        

         
        <input  type="submit" align="center" value="Create User">
      
              
        </div>         
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
  
  </html>


</body>
</html>
```

[image: RESULT Only Half form css working]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`password1` and `password2` are "custom" fields on the `UserCreationForm` since they do not exist as model fields on the `User` model. `Meta.widgets` will not work for these custom fields, you will need to redefine these fields and their widgets in your form

```
class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):

    password1 = forms.CharField(
        label="Password",
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'pass', 'type':'password', 'align':'center', 'placeholder':'password'}),
    )
    password2 = forms.CharField(
        label="Confirm password",
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'pass', 'type':'password', 'align':'center', 'placeholder':'password'}),
    )

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email']
        widgets={
            'username': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'un', 'type':'text', 'align':'center', 'placeholder':'UserName'}),
            'email':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'un', 'type':'text', 'align':'center', 'placeholder':'Email'}),
        }
```