# Password fields attribute not rendering correctly registration page Django

Tags: django

I'm creating a registration page in Django and everything works fine, and gets rendered correctly except the password fields. Why can that due to? I've tried building a form without the inbuild Django methods but it doesn't work either. It is very weird as I think all the code is working fine and everything is build correctly.

Here is the html:

```
<body class="bg-gradient-primary">

    <div class="container">

        <div class="card o-hidden border-0 shadow-lg my-5">
            <div class="card-body p-0">
                <!-- Nested Row within Card Body -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-5 d-none d-lg-block bg-register-image"></div>
                    <div class="col-lg-7">
                        <div class="p-5">
                            <div class="text-center">
                                <h1 class="h4 text-gray-900 mb-4">Create an Account!</h1>
                            </div>
                            <form class="user" method="POST">
                              {% csrf_token %}
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
                                      {{ form.first_name }}

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        {{ form.last_name }}


                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                  {{ form.email }}

                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
                                      {{ form.password1 }}

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        {{ form.password2 }}

                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block">
                                    Register Account
                                </button>

                                <hr>
                                <a href="index.html" class="btn btn-google btn-user btn-block">
                                    <i class="fab fa-google fa-fw"></i> Register with Google
                                </a>
                                <a href="index.html" class="btn btn-facebook btn-user btn-block">
                                    <i class="fab fa-facebook-f fa-fw"></i> Register with Facebook
                                </a>
                            </form>
                            <hr>
                            <div class="text-center">
                                <a class="small" href="forgot-password.html">Forgot Password?</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="text-center">
                                <a class="small" href="login.html">Already have an account? Login!</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript-->
    <script src='{% static "vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js" %}'></script>
  <script src='{% static "vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" %}'></script>

    <!-- Core plugin JavaScript-->
    <script src='{% static "vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js" %}'></script>

    <!-- Custom scripts for all pages-->
      <script src='{% static "js/sb-admin-2.min.js" %}'></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Here is the forms.py:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.forms import ModelForm, TextInput, PasswordInput, EmailInput
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = get_user_model()
        widgets = {
            'first_name': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control form-control-user', 'placeholder': 'First Name'}),
            'last_name': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control form-control-user', 'placeholder': 'Last Name'}),
            'email': EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control form-control-user', 'placeholder': 'Email Address'}),
            'password1': PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control form-control-user', 'placeholder': 'Password'}),
            'password2': PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control form-control-user', 'placeholder': 'Repeat Password'}),
        }
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email']
```

Here is the models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django import forms
# Create your models here.
class User(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40000)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40000)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=40000)
    password1 = models.CharField(max_length=40000)
    password2 = models.CharField(max_length=40000)

class Emails(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40000)
    urls = models.URLField(max_length=200)
    emails = models.TextField()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Here is the register page:

```
def register(request):

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('login')
    else:

        form = CreateUserForm()
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                messages.success(request, 'Account was created for' + user)
                return redirect('login')

    context = {'form':form}

    return render(request, 'leadfinderapp/register.html', context)
```

[image: Here is an image of the password fields]

Comment: I finally solved the issue. It is in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62502854/css-not-working-on-django-password-form-field

Answer (score 0):

---

**EDIT**

---

The parts you added allowed me to reproduce the problem

This works for me

```python
class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = get_user_model()
        widgets = {
            'first_name': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control form-control-user', 'placeholder': 'First Name'}),
            'last_name': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control form-control-user', 'placeholder': 'Last Name'}),
            'email': EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control form-control-user', 'placeholder': 'Email Address'}),
        }
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CreateUserForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['password1'].widget = PasswordInput(
            attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Password'})
        self.fields['password2'].widget = PasswordInput(
            attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Repeat Password'})
```

The answer is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49413185/django-password-fields-placeholder):

Comment: already tried, but when I put that, the server gets an error saying that those fields dont exist. What code you want of the project?

Comment: Another attempt I would make is to put `fields` on top of `widgets`.
If that doesn't work, add `models.py` and `views.py` files

Comment: still not working after putting fields above widgets. I've added models and views.

Comment: This didn't work for me but thank you anyways! I've posted the answer in comments of my question